# HTML anchor tag syntax

Tags: html, syntax, anchor

I am in a strange situation where I have to try to avoid matching a regex that is exactly the String `"</a>"` while still using that end anchor tag.

It seems to be that `"</a >"` works. Another possibility is `"</A>"` But I have to make sure it works 100%. As in, across all browsers. It's pretty bad for me if it doesn't.

Can I assume that this is safe, or do I have to figure out a different way of doing things?

Comment: html is case-insensitive, and browsers won't care about `</a>` and `</A>` looking different. xhtml, on the other hand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag names are case-insensitive in “classic” HTML, but not in XHTML, so using `</A>` is not safe at all if there is any possibility that the document will be processed as XHTML.

Any number of whitespace is allowed after a tag name, even in an end tag, according to both “classic HTML” rules (SGML rules) and XHTML rules (XML rules). It is practically certain that browsers get this right, i.e. that `</a >` is safe, since this is part of the very basic processing of tags